# Twilio - Python : NameError from Udacity Tutorial

Tags: python, sms, twilio

Hoping I could get input on what this error means and what I have to do to fix it. Thanks.

This is the error that appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/davidongchoco/Desktop/Python Programming/send_text.py", line 11, in <module>
    from_="+13348331130") # Replace with your Twilio number
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twilio/rest/resources/sms_messages.py", line 167, in create
    return self.create_instance(kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twilio/rest/resources/base.py", line 365, in create_instance
    data=transform_params(body))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twilio/rest/resources/base.py", line 200, in request
    resp = make_twilio_request(method, uri, auth=self.auth, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twilio/rest/resources/base.py", line 164, in make_twilio_request
    uri=resp.url, msg=message, code=code)
TwilioRestException: 
[31m[49mHTTP Error[0m [37m[49mYour request was:[0m

[36m[49mPOST https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACf37c4004688accd3f501ab2a2c9dc7e1/SMS/Messages.json[0m

[37m[49mTwilio returned the following information:[0m

[34m[49mPermission to send an SMS has not been enabled for the region indicated by the 'To' number: +639228902063.[0m

[37m[49mMore information may be available here:[0m

[34m[49mhttps://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21408[0m


>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The error has delivered a message to you that says:

> Permission to send an SMS has not been enabled for the region indicated by the 'To' number: +639228902063.
>
> More information may be available here:
>
> https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21408

If you follow that link, it tells you that you need to enable some global permissions on your account. You can do that here: https://www.twilio.com/user/account/settings/international/sms

It looks as though you are trying to send to a number from the Philippines, so make sure that check box is ticked.

Good luck with the Udacity course!